# デーモンの実行ユーザーを調べる方法

Tags: solaris

初歩的な質問ですみません。

Solaris11.3の環境です。

Windowsのサービスの実行ユーザーは、サービス画面のログオンタブから確認できますが、Solaris11.3の環境だと、どのように確認するのでしょうか？

ユーザーのパスワードを変更して問題がないかを確認するために調査しています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Service Management Facilityの管理コマンドで、例えば `svcprop dns/client:default`として出てきませんかね？手元にSolarisがないので確認できませんが。実行中であれば`ps`コマンドでわかりますね。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9399613.html